# Mearge two svg exports Fabric js

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

Hi I have two canvas on one page and I want to export them in one svg file:

```
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
  var canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  var ctx = canvas2.getContext('2d');
```

Is there any chance to merge them or to merge svg export how looks like his:

```
canvas.toSVG();
canvas2.toSVG();
```

Comment: how do you want to merge them? one over the other? one beside another? please be more specific and try to explain what you would like to obtain

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi I want to merge one over the other on first canvas is just background templates on second canvas are objects, text, images, Rect... and i need to export two cavnas like one canvas in SVG